# Apply discount at different rate levels

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a tool that takes the price of an item and the quantity being sold(Input by user). If quantity is 50 or more, buyer receivers a 20% discount. Anything 49 or below gets 10%. 
Current code returns 0

```
 Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click

    Dim a, b As Integer
    a = txtPrice.Text
    b = txtQuantity.Text
    If b >50 Then b = 0.2 
    If b <50 Then b = 0.1

    lblTotal.Text = (a * b) / 100

End Sub
```

I think I may have the percent part wrong? Hopefully someone can/will help.

Comment: Well, `b >= 50` and `b <= 50` means that anything **at** 50 will get both discounts, which is not what you want.  Your formula looks wrong as well - I think you want something like `a - (a * b)`.

Comment: uhm.. **"Anything 49 or below gets 10%."** should that be `If b <50 Then b = 0.1` because your code atm states `if b is less than OR equal to 50`

Comment: Now if the user enters 50 they get no discount.....and you're overwriting the value of `b` (the quantity) in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic appears to be a bit off, and you're overwriting the value of `b` before you calculate it.  Assuming (and I could be wrong) you want the total price after discount for the order, try this:

```
Dim price As Integer
Dim quantity As Double 

price = CInt(txtPrice.Text)
quantity = CDbl(txtQuantity.Text)

If quantity > = 50 Then
    lblTotal.Text = ((price * quantity) * 0.8).ToString()
Else
    lblTotal.Text = ((price * quantity) * 0.9).ToString()
End If
```

A couple of things to note here.

First, I used `CInt` and `CDbl` on the text from the textboxes.  VB.NET will (depending on your options) allow this, but it's bad form to get in the habit of allowing the compiler to convert values (from string in the textbox to int/double/decimal whatever) and will cause you headaches if you move to a strongly-typed language like C# or Java.

Secondly, I used 0.8 for the 20% discount (because in reality they're getting it for 80%) and 0.9 for the 10% discount.   This calculation assumes the discount is off the total of the order, if it's not you'll need to adjust the formula accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Tim nailed it. Thanks tim.

```
Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click

Dim a, b As Integer
a = txtPrice.Text
b = txtQuantity.Text
If b >=50 Then b = 0.2 
If b <50 Then b = 0.1

lblTotal.Text = (a * b) / 100
End Sub
```

'needed to repleace "(a * b) /100" with "a - (a * b)"

Comment: Note that formula may still be incorrect, since it's will work out as (a * 0.2/0.1) / 100, which may not be what you want.  Another option would be to reassign `a` to be `a = a * .01/.02`, but it really depends on what you expect the total amount to be (where the discount is applied).

Comment: In de code above,what hapens if you order 50... Nothing. make it >49

Comment: what would it have to be to include 50 in the 20% level?

Comment: @King96 - It's correct.  `If b >= 50` and `If b < 50`.

Comment: Option Strict is your friend use it! Also try parse would fit nice as well, unless your making sure its the correct datatype in the textbox fields, otherwise youll throw a nasty exception...